# Entry should not be greater than a specific fix number

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a template where i want that My total row value should not be more than 4. if user try to enter more than 4 so its should strict and show a msgbox to user saying that Enter time in another slot.

*VBA EXCEL*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
If Range("A1:AS15").Value > 4 Then
MsgBox "Invalid entry. Enter value in another slot!", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

This code is working for me but once click on ok button the value is getting insert into that cell, it should not enter in that cell.

Comment: Also i believe you should add another security measure to avoid inserting characters - letters if you want only numbers.

Comment: You're checking a range that has 15 rows, are you trying to check if the sum of the entries for each row is less than 4 or are trying to check if the sum of the whole range is less than 4?  OR  are trying to count the number of entries in the whole range or the number of entries in each row?

Comment: i am trying to check count of row should not be more than 4. (e.g. Range A1:A10 user will enter time like 00:30 min and A11 will be count of total employee entered time but i need that only any 4 employee can enter the time, once 5th one is going to enter the time he should get an msg that already 4 entries are done. Please provide me a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try:

Steps:

1. Open VBA Editor
2. Double click on the sheet you want to import the code (the sheet where Range("A1:AS15" appears).
3. Insted of **General** (the left horizontal box - select **Workbook**).
4. Instead of **SelectionChange** (the right horizontal box - select 
   **Change**).
5. Between:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   End Sub
   ```

Import:

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:AS15")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value > 4 Then
            MsgBox "Invalid entry. Enter value in another slot!", vbRetryCancel + vbExclamation
            Target.Value = ""
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: Yes, i have pasted above code in new module and not getting any output

Comment: You don't want this in a separate module, you want it on the worksheet.  Go back to @Error1004's post and follow each step.  Just change  "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub" to "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub

Comment: i am trying to check count of row should not be more than 4. (e.g. Range A1:A10 user will enter time like 00:30 min and A11 will be count of total employee entered time but i need that only any 4 employee can enter the time, once 5th one is going to enter the time he should get an msg that already 4 entries are done. Please provide me a solution for this –